# rewrite rule in htaccess

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I have a website structured:

```
- root
  - .htaccess
  - wordpress installation
  - folder xxx
    - wordpress
```

In my .htaccess I have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that it don't allow me to go in:

```
www.mywebsite.it/xxx
```

because a loop redirection happen.
If I erase the rule, all goes good.
How can I modify it?
I want that if user type mywebsite.it/ or mywebsite.it/xxx, it is redirected to www version.

my .htaccess:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule works in isolation but Wordpress stuff is hijacking over it. Slightly modified rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

1. Make sure **this is 1st rule after `RewriteEngine On` line** in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`
2. make sure in `WP permalink structure` you have site address with `www.` otherwise WP will again send it back to non-www
3. If you have any `.htaccess` below root then they should this additional line below `RewriteEngine On` line:

   ```
   RewriteOptions Inherit
   ```

Also test in a different browser to avoid 301 caching.

Comment: Post your root .htaccess and `xxx/.htaccess`

Comment: i have only one htaccess in root folder

Comment: Also make sure in WP `permalink` structure you have site address with `www.` otherwise WP will again send it back to non-www

Comment: You're welcome. URL rewrites with WP installations are tricky to deal with, glad that it worked out for you.